# Exporting same named Data Frames from separate lists into their own excel documents

Tags: r

I have five lists of Data frames. I am trying to write an apply function or a for loop that will pull similar named Dataframes from the five lists, put them into separate spreadsheets and then export them as excel documents.

So I started with a large excel document with 5 spreadsheets (I'll call it "ORIGINAL_DOCUMENT". I used a split function to create lists based on column value:

`LIST_DF <- ORIGINAL_DOCUMENT%>% base::split(., .$COMPANY_NAME)`

Here's a kind of visual example of what I'm seeing in R right now:

```
|List 1    | List 2   |    |   List 3 | List 4   | List 5 |
| -------- | -------- |    | -------- | -------- | -------| 
| DF 1     | DF 1     |    | DF 1     | DF 1     | DF 1   |  
| DF 2     | DF 2     |    | DF 2     | DF 2     | DF 2   |
```

I would like the output to create an excel document with DF 1 from each list saved as a spreadsheet and so on. For every excel document, I want the spreasheets named the same (Company1, Company2, Company3, Company 4 and Company 5.)

I could really appreaciate any advice/help out there. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the format of the original data (after you load it into R - I'm not sure what the relevance of 5 spreadsheets is - unless you want to repeat this 5 times?) and what you want the content of each output excel file should look like?  Small dummy data is fine - so (for example) columns "company name" and "x" with about 1-2 rows per company is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibly way how we could do it:

```
# create a list of dataframes
df_list <- lapply(1:5, function(x) {
  data.frame(COMPANY_NAME = c("A", "B"), values = rnorm(2))
})

# name  list
names(df_list) <- paste0("df", 1:5)

# Loop through each data frame
for (df_name in df_names) {
  
  # Create a new workbook
  wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
  
  # Add a worksheet for each list
  for (i in seq_along(lists)) {
    df <- lists[[i]][[df_name]]
    openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, paste0("Company", i))
    openxlsx::writeData(wb, paste0("Company", i), df)
  }
  
  # Save the workbook
  openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(df_name, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

[image]